# Classes/PHPExcel_Shared_String.php): failed to open stream

Tags: php, phpexcel

This question was asked in 2010.  I am seeing a related problem but the recommended solutions from 2010 don't fix it.

I am using PHPExcel v 1.8.0 (March 2014)

The suggestions made on the original reply have been incorporated and the rest of the system still works normally, for example I have an init.php file that is brought in for every scrip which includes the following as suggested in an earlier post:

```
function myAutoload($Class)
{
   require_once 'Classes/' . $Class . '.php';
}
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoad')
```

All {classes.php} files are in the Classes/ folder off the document root including, of course PHPExcel.php. The PHPExcel folder is also contained in the Classes/ folder.

I have tried various ways of spinning up PHPExcel, including the usual

```
$spreadsheet = new PHPExcel;
```

As an alternative I also tried defining a Spreadsheet class

```
Class Spreadsheet extends PHPExcel {.... }
```

They all produce the same error as cut and paste into the above

I have successfully ported over the remainder of the processes in the application from a procedural style to object orientated system, and it has been well worth the weeks that have been spent on it. This last hurdle with PHPExcel however has got me foxed!

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your autoloader to return a false if it can't load the specified file:

```
function myAutoload($Class)
{
    if (file_exists('Classes/' . $Class . '.php')) {
        require_once 'Classes/' . $Class . '.php';
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

That way, autoloading will from through your own autoloader and execute the next autoloader in the "queue" (the PHPExcel autoloader) if it doesn't find the requested file through your own autoloader. If you don't return a `false` the SPL autoloader handler won't bother working through any other "queued" autoloaders

Comment: Brilliant !!  It works perfectly with just the obvious extra pair of parentheses in the if () statement line.